# Details are not shown for Internal Server Error [500] even after setting the IncludeErrorDetailPolicy to Always

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, owin

I am not seeing the error details even after the **IncludeErrorDetailPolicy** to **Always**

I have the below code in Startup.cs.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always
```

Is there anything else I need to do? I can get the whole error information in my local machine, but not in the DEV server after it is deployed.

I logged into the server and made the customError mode set to "On". Also, I set the httpErrors set to "Detailed".

```
<system.web>    
    <customErrors mode="On"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>    
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
</system.webServer>
```

It did not show after those changes as well. Is there anything else need to be done in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not an answer. It is a workaround:

I removed the below code from Startup.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always
```

Added the below in web.config in system.webServer section:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Detailed" />
```

Also, I used the `ResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage)` instead of `InternalServerError(Exception)` as below:

```
private IHttpActionResult CustomHttpActionResult(string message)
{
   return ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage
   {
      Content = new StringContent(message),
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
   });
}
```